# Configure Forms Authentication Without Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, forms-authentication, global-asax

### **Scenario**

---

I've configured my MVC application to use Forms authentication in the traditional fashion.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="1">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

However, I allow the client to choose how his web application authenticates (URL Token / Cookie), as well as how long his application session should last before expiring (Timeout)

### **Question**

---

Is there a way for me to do this via code? I've only seen implementations of this via web.config?

I'd like to read the settings from the database and apply them in Global.asax -> OnApplicationStart()

Comment: http://www.justskins.com/forums/programatically-change-authentication-mode-242910.html

Comment: Hi @artm Thank you for the link, however, this is just manipulating the web.config file. I'd like to do away with the config file setup all together.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5353/Custom-Authentication-provider-by-implementing-IHt

Comment: Did you look at this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805466/programmatically-enable-forms-authentication-in-iis-7-0

Comment: And: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.enableformsauthentication(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you have AssemblyInfo.cs file in Properties or some other folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [WebActivatorEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebActivatorEx/2.0.0). Here's a good [blog](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/02/new-features-in-webactivator-13.html) about its capabilities. To configure FormsAuthentication, you'd have to execute your configuration method even before the application starts. WebActivatorEx will handle that for you. You could specify this *[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(AppConfig), "Configure")]* in the AssemblyInfo.cs class if you don't want to use third party packages. [Here's another point of reference that talks about it.](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx/)

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(AppConfig), "Configure")]
public static class AppConfig
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        var settings = new NameValueCollection();
        settings.Add("defaultUrl", "~/Account/Default.aspx");
        settings.Add("loginUrl", "~/Default.aspx");
        settings.Add("timeout", "10");
        FormsAuthentication.EnableFormsAuthentication(settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm awarding you the bounty even though I ended up just managing forms authentication manually (had to manage sliding expiration manually anyways, and it's really not much more)

Comment: Hmm, was after the question not a bounty but I sure appreciate it.

Comment: A caveat, which I only discovered after a few weeks of thinking this was working as I intended: You can only set the default url and login url this way. That was so odd to me, but it was ignoring my path and domain and I later learned the only reason it seemed to be working was because my application was inheriting its forms settings from the parent application above it and those settings were what I was wanting to match for shared auth cookies anyway.