# in C# mvc 5 read write system.webServer section in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have an mvc 5 web application. I wanted to switch authentication between sql and active directory at run time.

For this I figured out that I have to change web.config.

- For SQL under `System.Web` I have to set

> authentication mode="None"

plus under `system.webServer` I have to set under

```
  <authentication>
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
  </authentication>
```

- For AD under `System.Web` I have to set

> authentication mode="Windows"

plus under `system.webServer` I have to set under

```
  <authentication>
    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
  </authentication>
```

I tried searching here on SO and found few link . It's still not working.
Here are some links I tried

[Programmatically enable or disable anonymous authentication in IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419304/programmatically-enable-or-disable-anonymous-authentication-in-iis)

This one looks like should be working , but I even after running the code I don't see any changes in web.config file.

[Programmatically enable forms authentication in IIS 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805466/programmatically-enable-forms-authentication-in-iis-7-0)

Anyone have good answer with proven results?

Thanks.

Comment: Changing web.config at runtime will cause application restart. This may become serious issue as all in process requests will be aborted.

Comment: Publish two web apps with different authentication preconfigured. Then switch between them at runtime.

Comment: @PankajKapare I am fine with application restart. I actually want that. lex Li I think I read that before. Not sure how to do and if I really want it that way. Buy my main question is , whether it is possible to do what I want.